# Where do I see the shell script output in Hudson

Tags: hudson

I have written a shell script to build my project using hudson. 
I have put some comments that will be displayed on the console by using echo command. This will help me to debug the scripts if there are any errors. Rigt now the script works fine without any bugs. But in future if there are any errors, I would like to See the logs and identify which part/command of the script is causing the problem.

In this regard I have two questions: 1. Where can I find the logs or the output of the build scripts? 2. Where can I see the hudson log files? I have started hudson by placing the hudson.war file under webapps folder of Tomcat.

Answer (score 4):

1. You should be able to see the console output for each build by choosing the "Console" menu option on the build menu on the left of the page.
2. The Hudson logs are visible from within Hudson itself. Just go to "Manage Hudson" on the main menu, then choose "System Log".

I'm not sure if that's exactly what you were looking for. If not, please clarify and I'll try help.

Comment: I believe you have to be logged in to do either action (if your Hudson instance uses authentication, which is not the default).